# how to get content of message in shielded transactions?

Tags: tezos-client, rpc, privacy

I have a message send with tezos-client like:
tezos-client sapling forge transaction 10 from alice to zet13Alicexxxxxx using sap  --message 'test'

How to get content of send message in shielded transactions?

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED**

It is not provided by the client binary yet.

https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/-/issues/1074

Comment: Unshield allows me to withdraw tokens from sapling contract, but I don't see any way to use it to get any details of shielded transaction send to user (messages and balances of each comming transaction)

Comment: It is not provided by the client yet.

https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/-/issues/1074